# How to open a graphical connection to a remote server so that I can run PyCharm from it

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, terminal

I have a remote server on which Ubuntu is installed. I asked the sysadmins to install PyCharm on it. I will then need to open a graphics connection to the server (indulge me if the terminology is not correct, but I think the idea is clear), from my Windows 10 laptop. Is that possible? How can I do that?

As terminal, I have Git Bash installed on my laptop. I can install other terminals if you tell me which one (or even the WSL if you think it would help). But then I need to know how (if at all possible) to open a graphical connection from these terminals.

Ideally I would also need to know which other software the sysadmins should install on the server to make this possible, but I can ask another question if necessary to follow the site guidelines. In that case, please assume all necessary software has been installed on the server.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things.

First, install an X server on Windows. There are a few options. I've used Xming and it worked. There's also Cygwin/X which you install with Cygwin.

Now you can start an SSH tunnel. The command should look something like this:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 ssh -X ubuntu
```

You will then have a prompt at which you can run what you need.

You can also use MobaXterm. It already has everything you need, so just check X11 Forwarding when you create the connection.

Comment: 1. what about [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), would it be a good X server on Windows? I installed it and it seems very easy to use. 2. instead than `localhost:0.0`, shouldn't I use my IP address? How can I find it on Windows? Would `ipconfig` serve the purpose?

Comment: 1. That should work. It seems to have a built in X server. 2. No, it should be exactly that if you're doing it from git bash. From MobaXterm, you don't need to do anything of the sort. Just check X11 Forwarding when you create the connection.

Comment: I like [vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) as an xserver.  I have had font issues with other xservers on windows

Comment: Mobaxterm works perfectly, the only thing to not forget is check X11 forwarding, no need to set DISPLAY manually